# SSMS New query tab not showing spid

Tags: sql-server, ssms

My SSMS;

[image]

Other SSMS;

[image]

Not showing spid and not showing execute query.

Tool>Options>Editor Tab and Status Bar> All True

Thank you advance.

Comment: It's not connecting - are you in single user mode?

Comment: I have a connection. I can execute query. Not single mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem.

Options by SQL Complete;[image]

Answer (score 1):

In SSMS 2017, they moved the SPID location down to the bottom right hand side of the query window.

There it shows: Server (Version) | User(spid) | Database | Elapsed Time | Rows Returned

Comment: if the user name is too long then you need to move the  mouse over ... to see the spid no